# How do you put a String variable in the Robot Class KeyEvent parameter?

Tags: java, string, keypress, keyevent, awtrobot

I am using the Robot Class in Java, and I created a static method for pressing a key. My problem is that I want to be able to press whichever key using input from my main method, but the parameters for the keyPress method and keyRelease method do not accept String. And I don't want to use a lot of if statements to press that key. Here is my code:

```
public static void keyType(String key) throws AWTException {
  Robot r = new Robot();
  r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
}
```

Now I want to use the key variable (input from my main method) to decide which key to press. I planned to just use a capital letter in the String (such as "A", or "B"), and replace the (KeyEvent.VK_A) in the keyPress and keyRelease parameters with (KeyEvent.VK_ + key). But then I realized that it didn't accept or use String parameters, so what do I do?

Comment: declare String key variable in class area. so you can access it from `keyType` method

Comment: I get that, but my problem is that I can't put the key variable in the KeyEvent parameter. I wanted to do something like, `(KeyEvent.VK_ + key)` but the KeyEvent parameter is not of the String type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question , you can parse keycode to robot keypress method .you can't use `KeyEvent.VK_+"A"` but you can use `65`.
instead `KeyEvent.VK_A` you can use `65` which is key code for `A`.

```
private void keyType(char key) {

    int keyCode = (int) key;

    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
}
```

if you view the source code of `keyEvent.class` you can see what is actually `VK_N` is .it's just a mapped int with keycodes.

```
public class KeyEvent extends InputEvent {

    public static final int VK_A = 65;
    public static final int VK_B = 66;
    public static final int VK_C = 67;
    public static final int VK_D = 68;
    public static final int VK_E = 69;
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped! I just wrote ta similar thing below, and your answer came up just as I was typing mine! Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out another way to do this. The parameter for this argument is int, so I found the key codes for each key on the keyboard, starting with A (65). Now I can successfully get input from the keyboard. If anyone else would like to see the link, here it is: [Key Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-key-codes).